# Find CDF of uniformly distributed variable

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed over $[-1,3]$ and $Y=X^2$. Find the CDF $F_{Y}(y)$

From definition, I know that X's PDF is 
$\displaystyle f_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}, & -1\leq x\leq 3,  \\
0, & \text{otherwise}. 
\end{cases}$

Thus $\displaystyle F_{Y}(y)=P(X^2\leq y)=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}f_{X}(x)dx$. Besides, $0\leq Y \leq9$, thus $F_{Y}(y)=0$, when $y<0$ and $F_{Y}(y)=1$, when $y>9$

Due to fact, that integral depends on $y$, I need to split interval into few parts. Any tips, on how to choose $y$ intervals? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0\le y\le 1$, we have $Y\le y$ if and only if $-\sqrt{y}\le X\le \sqrt{y}$.  But for $0\le y\le 1$, 
$$\Pr(-\sqrt{y}\le X\le \sqrt{y})=\frac{2\sqrt{y}}{4}.$$ 
The reason is that the interval from $-\sqrt{y}$ to $\sqrt{y}$ has length $2\sqrt{y}$.

For $1\lt y\lt 9$, we still want the probability that $-\sqrt{y}\le X\le \sqrt{y}$. However, $X$ "can't" be below $-1$. So equivalently we want the probability that $-1\le X\le \sqrt{y}$. The interval now has length $\sqrt{y}-(-1)=\sqrt{y}+1$, so the required probability is 
$$\frac{\sqrt{y}+1}{4}.$$

**Remark:** For the uniform distribution, setting up integrals is unnecessary. However, the cdf is always given by 
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} f(x)\,dx$$
where $f(x)$ is the density function of $X$. But we must take account of the fact that the density function is $0$ to the left of $-1$. so for $0\le y\le 1$, we have
$$F_Y(y)=\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{dx}{4},$$
while for $1\lt y\le 9$ we get 
$$F_Y(y)=\int_{-1}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{dx}{4}.$$
(The lower bound is $1$, not $-\sqrt{y}$, because the density function of $X$ to the left of $-1$ is $0$, not $\frac{1}{4}$.)

Comment: Could you tell me, how you chose those intervals?

Comment: When $0\le y\le 1$, we have that $Y\le y$ if and only if $X$ lies between $-\sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt{y}$. And now we can compute the probability easily. When $1\lt y\le 3$, it is still true that $Y\le y$ iff $-\sqrt{y}\le X\le \sqrt{y}$, but $-\sqrt{y}$ gets us into a region where the density function of $X$ is $0$, so we must adjust. But I will add a different explanation to the main answer.

Comment: Thank so much for clear explanation! It makes random process' look really easy : )

Comment: You are welcome. It is not at all easy, but with practice one can become reasonably comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ranges for Y and X as follows:

- $0 < y < 1$ which is equivalent to $-1 < x < 1$ which is equivalent to
  ${-\sqrt y}$ to ${\sqrt y}$
- $1 < y < 9$ which is equivalent to $1 < x < 3$ which is equivalent to $1$ to ${\sqrt y}$ Not $-1$ to ${\sqrt y}$

Can you clarify range for $1 < y < 9$ in more detail.